# Checkquear un solo checkbox Android Studio

Tags: xml, checkbox

Esto no es para preguntar, es mi primer comentario aquí, el siguiente código es para ayudar al que lo requiera (como seleccionar un solo checkbox cuando hay varios), este es mi código de XML y Kotlin en Android Studio, si hay más gente que desee ayudar encantado. GRACIAS!!!

```
<CheckBoxandroid:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMasculino"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Masculino"
        />
<CheckBoxandroid:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxFemenino"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Femenino"
        />
<CheckBoxandroid:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxOtro"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Otro"
        />
```

KOTLIN Aqui esta el código kotlin, lo hice con binding, (Los checkbox estan habilitados cuando ninguno ha sido seleccionado, una vez sea seleccionado alguno se desabilitan los demás, y si se cliquea nuevamente ese checkbox habilitado todos los checkbox quedan habilitados.) Eso es todo.

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initDate()

    }

    private fun initDate()
    {
        checkBox()
    }

    private fun checkBox()
    {
        binding.checkBoxMasculino.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _: CompoundButton, _:Boolean ->
            if(binding.checkBoxMasculino.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxFemenino.isEnabled = false
                binding.checkBoxOtro.isEnabled = false
            }
            else if(!binding.checkBoxMasculino.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxFemenino.isEnabled = true
                binding.checkBoxOtro.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        binding.checkBoxFemenino.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _: CompoundButton, _:Boolean ->
            if(binding.checkBoxFemenino.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxMasculino.isEnabled = false
                binding.checkBoxOtro.isEnabled = false
            }
            else if(!binding.checkBoxFemenino.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxMasculino.isEnabled = true
                binding.checkBoxOtro.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        binding.checkBoxOtro.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _: CompoundButton, _:Boolean ->
            if(binding.checkBoxOtro.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxMasculino.isEnabled = false
                binding.checkBoxFemenino.isEnabled = false//Corregir aqui es femenino GRACIASSSS SUSCRIBETE|
            }
            else if(!binding.checkBoxOtro.isChecked)
            {
                binding.checkBoxMasculino.isEnabled = true
                binding.checkBoxFemenino.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask]. Este espacio es para preguntas únicamente. Si bien tu intención es buena, para llevarla a cabo de forma correcta y que ayude al sitio, te recomiendo que en este espacio de pregunta dejes la parte del problema o la pregunta justamente y te contestes a ti mismo con la respuesta y/o solución. Así ayudaras a las personas que tienen esta duda

Comment: La idea es buena, pero justo para eso existen los **radio buttons**. Esto puede confundir a alguien y lo mínimo que debes hacer es colocar un tooltip indicando que si quieren cambiar de opción seleccionada primero deben desmarcar el check seleccionado antes. Pero supongo que a alguien le puede llegar a ser de utilidad... [edit] tu pregunta y respóndela tu mismo para seguir con la dinámica del sitio.